# error in finding the relative path in MFC program when calling exe file

Tags: c++

I use VS2010 in windows 7 to build a C++ MFC program.
In this program, I want to call an Example.exe file in the same folder.
But it says "can not find the Example.exe file". I think this is the relative path problem in C++, but I do not know how to solve it.

I have tried:

```
1./Example.exe

2 \\Example.exe
```

None of these works

```
 void call_exe()
{

SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExecInfo = {0};
shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
shExecInfo.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
shExecInfo.hwnd   = NULL;
shExecInfo.lpVerb = _T("open");
shExecInfo.lpFile = _T("./Example.exe");
shExecInfo.lpParameters = "";
shExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
shExecInfo.nShow        = SW_SHOW;
shExecInfo.hInstApp     = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&shExecInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(shExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);


}
```

Expected results: the Example.exe in the same folder could be called by the MFC program.
Actual results: The MFC program could not find the Example.exe in the same folder.

Comment: Backslash needs to be escaped as `"\\"`.

Comment: I tried shExecInfo.lpFile = _T("\\Example.exe"); but it still could not find the exe.

Comment: Well, what is the current working directory of the program? How is that directory related to the directory where you have the file? Relative directories are relative to the working directory of the running process.

Comment: Both the MFC program and the Example.exe are in D://

Comment: If you want to execute something related to program directory then you should query path to program using `GetModuleFileName`, extract folder path and form path to program to be launched.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your meaning. Both my MFC program and the example.exe is in D://. Could you show me the corrected  code that I could call the  example.exe  in MFC program.

Comment: And are you certain that the current directory of your program when you run it is `"D:\"`? You can use the [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) function to find out. Or you could specify the absolute path to the file, as in `_T("D:\\Example.exe")`. Or as mentioned by @VTT, use [`GetModuleFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea).